# How to find the time overlap in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get the count of start time overlap for DocID

In the below example 9:00-9:15 overlaps in 9:00-9:30
So i want the count as 2 for DocID (111)

```
=============================================================
EncID   |  Pid   |  DocID  |  Date     | StartTime | EndTime|
=============================================================
1       |  11    |  111    | 25/3/2016 | 9:00      | 9:30   |    
2       |  12    |  111    | 25/3/2016 | 9:00      | 9:15   |    
3       |  13    |  111    | 26/3/2016 | 10:00     | 10:30  |    
=============================================================





Expected Out put
==============
DocID | count|
==============
111   |  2   |
==============
```

Comment: self join the table on a.DocID = B.DocID WHERE Min(A.StartTime) <= Min(B.StartTime) AND  Max(A.EndTime) >= MAX(B.EndTime)

Comment: I forgot to include a join on DATE.  I am assuming that you want date and time overlap, and not just time.  I.E.  two records exactly 24 hours apart that have overlapping start and end times should not be included in the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work and avoids `OR`. The subquery should run efficiently.

```
SELECT 
    T1.DocID,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM [Table] T2
        WHERE T1.DocID = T2.DocID
            AND T1.[Date] = T2.[Date]
            AND T1.StartTime <= T2.EndTime
            AND T1.EndTime >= T2.StartTime
    ) AS [Count]
FROM [Table] T1
GROUP BY
    T1.DocID
```

If you're also wanting to filter to only show records with overlap, it's probably best to convert the sub-query to a join (not any more efficient, but definitely easier to filter):

```
SELECT 
    T1.DocID,
    COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM [Table] T1
    INNER JOIN [Table] T2
        ON T1.DocID = T2.DocID
            AND T1.[Date] = T2.[Date]
            AND T1.StartTime <= T2.EndTime
            AND T1.EndTime >= T1.EndTime
GROUP BY
    T1.DocID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```